# How to obtain the 'reason'/cause for an AccessDeniedException in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security

We're using Spring Security 3.1.3-RELEASE with method-level security. It works perfectly.

I'd like to log, and maybe show to the user, **why** he is getting denied access.

Using a `org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl` subclass, I can get a reference to the `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException` thrown, but I can't find a way to determine what caused it (eg, 'Missing role ROLE_ADMIN' or something to that effect).

Am I missing something, or does it simply not exist?

Comment: same problem here. It would be nice if AccessDecisionVoters not only return  ACCESS_GRANTED or ACCESS_DENIED but return an AccessDeniedDecision which can hold a reason/cause

Comment: I created a jira issue:  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2148

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with default implementations available in Spring Security.

I investigated source code and...

`MethodSecurityInterceptor` is responsible for protecting method invocations. It delegates access decisions to `AccessDecisionManager`. 
I checked every implementation of `AccessDecisionManager` available out of box.

- AffirmativeBased
- ConsensusBased
- UnanimousBased

Each of them throws `AccessDeniedException` exception in similar way.

```
case AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_DENIED:
                throw new AccessDeniedException(
                      messages.getMessage("AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied",
                      "Access is denied")
                 );
```

`AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied` is name of the message, which can be localized.

For English it is:

```
AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied=Access is denied
```

There are several languages available out of box, and you can make you own translations, but...

That's all, no more information about reasons of exception.

More information about localization of exception messages:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#localization

Answer (score 1):

I also created a jira issue for that: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3104

`@PreAuthorize, @PostAuthorize, @Secured` annotation can have a parameter to point custom message property in order to set detailed & more user friendly exception messages.

This could also be done by providing a param. to define an class name that extends `AccessDeniedException` to raise to you let users handle the rest.

This way, while processing complex rules like

`@PreAuthorize("record.createuser != authentication.getName()")`

We can get a defined error like

`"You cannot process a record that you created.""` etc. instead of `"Access is denied"`

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a solution which works (only) for authorization annotations used in the API layer (e.g. with @RequestMapping). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64846057/4413638