# Custom Error message with @Preauthorize and @@ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

We are using spring and spring-security-3.2. Recently We are adding annotations @PreAuthorize to RestAPIs(earlier it was URL based).

```
     @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('salesorder','ViewSalesOrder')")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/restapi/salesorders/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView getSalesOrders(){}
```

We already have Global exception handler which annotated with - @ControllerAdvice and custom PermissionEvaluator in place, everything works fine except the error message.

Lets say some user is accessing API At moment without having 'ViewSalesOrder' permission then spring by default throws the exception 'Access is denied',but didn't tell which permission is missing (Its our requirement to mention which permission is missing).

Is it possible to throw an exception which also include the permission name, so final error message should be look like "Access is denied, you need ViewSalesOrder permission"(here permission name should be from @PreAuthorize annotation)?

Please note that we have 100 such restAPI in place so generic solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what solution did you go with? I still cant find a way to set custom error message

Answer (score 6):

There is no pretty way of achieving what you expect since `PermissionEvaluator`  interface doesn't let you pass the missing permission along with the result of the evaluation.
In addition, `AccessDecisionManager` decides on the final authorization with respect to the votes of the `AccessDecisionVoter` instances, one of which is `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter` which votes with respect to the evaluation of `@PreAuthorize` value.
Long story short, `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter` votes against the request (giving the request –1 point) when your custom `PermissionEvaluator` returns `false` to `hasPermission` call. As you see there is no way to propagate the cause of the failure in this flow.

On the other hand, you may try some workarounds to achieve what you want.
 One way can be to throw an exception within your custom `PermissionEvaluator` when permission check fails. You can use this exception to propagate the missing permission to your global exception handler. There, you can pass the missing permission to your message descriptors as a parameter. Beware that this will halt execution process of `AccessDecisionManager` which means successive voters will not be executed (defaults are [RoleVoter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html) and [AuthenticatedVoter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html)). You should be careful if you choose to go down this path.
Another safer but clumsier way can be to implement a custom [AccessDeniedHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html) and customize the error message before responding with 403. `AccessDeniedHandler` provides you current `HttpServletRequest` which can be used to retrieve the request URI. However, bad news in this case is, you need a URI to permission mapping in order to locate the missing permission.

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented the second possible solution mentioned by Mert Z. My solution works only for @PreAuthorize annotations used in the API layer (e.g. with @RequestMapping). I have registered a custom AccessDeniedHandler bean in which I get the value of the @PreAuthorize annotation of the forbidden API method and fills it into error message.

```java
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (!response.isCommitted()) {
            List<HandlerMapping> handlerMappings = dispatcherServlet.getHandlerMappings();
            if (handlerMappings != null) {
                HandlerExecutionChain handler = null;
                for (HandlerMapping handlerMapping : handlerMappings) {
                    try {
                        handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    if (handler != null)
                        break;
                }
                if (handler != null && handler.getHandler() instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                    HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler.getHandler();
                    PreAuthorize methodAnnotation = method.getMethodAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
                    if (methodAnnotation != null) {
                        response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
                                "Authorization condition not met: " + methodAnnotation.value());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
                    HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }

    @Inject
    public void setDispatcherServlet(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        this.dispatcherServlet = dispatcherServlet;
    }
}
```

The handler is registered in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public abstract class BaseSecurityInitializer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

Beware that if there is also a global resource exception handler with @ControllerAdvice the CustomAccessDeniedHandler won't be executed. I solved this by rethrowing the exception in the global handler (as advised here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6908):

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResourceExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity accessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e) throws AccessDeniedException {
        log.info(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this where the PreAuthorize annotation in service layer

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an *org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException* from a method that was called inside an EL-Expression:

```
@PreAuthorize("@myBean.myMethod(#myRequestParameter)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the `@PreAuthorize` annotation should be supporting `String message();` in addition to the SpEl value. But, for whatever reason, it does not. Most of the suggestions here seem unnecessarily cumbersome and elaborate. As @lathspell has suggested, the simplest way to provide your own error message - along with any custom access validation logic - would be to add a simple method that performs the check and throws the `AccessDeniedException` in case the check fails, and then reference that method in the SpEl expression. Here's an example:

```html
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor // if you use lombok
public class OrderController {  
    
    private final OrderService orderService;  
    ...
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/salesorders", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("@orderController.hasPermissionToSeeOrders(#someArgOfThisMethod)")
    public Page<OrderDto> getSalesOrders(
                          // someArgOfThisMethod here, perhaps HttpRequest, @PathVariable, @RequestParam, etc. 
                          int pageIndex, int pageSize, String sortBy, String sortOrder) {
        Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.Direction.fromString(sortOrder), sortBy);
        return ordersService.retrieveSalesOrders(..., pageRequest);
    }

    public static Boolean hasPermissionToSeeOrders(SomeArgOfTheTargetMethod argToEvaluate) {
        //check eligibility to perform the operation based on some data from the incoming objects (argToEvaluate)
        if (condition fails) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Your message");
        }
        return true;
    }
```