# Customize AccessDeniedException to get what permission is missing

Tags: spring-security, access-denied

I'm using Spring boot 3.0.6, so Spring Security 6.0.3.

Lets supose I do have an endpoint with a @PreAuthorize and a Authority defined

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/perfil")
public class ProfileController {
    @GetMapping({ "/all" })
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ROL_PROFILE_ADMINISTRATION')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Profile>> findAll() {
        List<Profile> list = profileService.findAllProfiles();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Profile>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Also, I do have a `@RestControllerAdvice` in a class that implements `ErrorController`. There, I'm handling general errors such as `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` or `AccessDeniedException`.

This is the code:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class BaseExceptionHandler implements ErrorController {
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> accessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        String msg = StringUtils.isBlank(ex.getMessage()) ? NOT_ENOUGH_PERMISSIONS : ex.getMessage(); 
        return crearHttpResponse (HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, msg); 
    }

        @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> methodNotSupportedtException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException e) {
        HttpMethod methodAllowed = Objects.requireNonNull(e.getSupportedHttpMethods()).iterator().next();
        return crearHttpResponse (HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, String.format(METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, methodAllowed)); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can adapt the returning message of the `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` using the `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.getSupportedHttpMethods()`, so it looks like

```
That verb is not allowed for the endpoint. Please, make a '%s' request
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing with the `AccessDeniedException`, informing the user the `role` the user is missing. Is there a way to access it?

I have been diving into Spring Security `AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor` and the `attemptAuthorization` throws `new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");`, so I'm afraid I cannot.

I was tempted to open an issue, but I prefer asking here first.

I also checked [Custom Error message with @Preauthorize and @@ControllerAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060023/custom-error-message-with-preauthorize-and-controlleradvice) which goes with a pretty similar question, but was related to spring security 3.0.2, so maybe there are better ways of doing what [Jan Tomášek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64846057/2087103) did.

Comment: `informing the user the role the user is missing` giving security information out to the client is _very bad practice_ as this can lead on users with malicious intents to understand what they are doing wrong in their hacker attempts.

Comment: I know this, but it would really help the front dev team.

Comment: then make sure the dev team instead can read the logs which will give exact information.